# Libgdx the correct way to make a game

Tags: java, libgdx

Recently I started making my "first" real RPG (The other 'RPG's' were text based in batch or whatever). I am using Libgdx, since from what I read it's pretty simple to get the hang of.

But what I'm interested in is am I doing it right?

For example I make a TiledMap and draw the camera etc. everything 'semi works', but is it right? On one tutorial there was a person which created thread's and much more, so it's making me think I'm doing it wrong

For example this is my GameScreen

```java
public class GameScreen implements Screen, Runnable{
      private MenuScreen menuScreen;
        SpriteBatch batch, infobatch;
        BitmapFont font;

        private int tileWidth, tileHeight,
        mapWidthInTiles, mapHeightInTiles,
        mapWidthInPixels, mapHeightInPixels;

        private float delta;
        private InputHandler inputHandler;

        private TiledMap map;
        private AssetManager manager;
        private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
        private OrthographicCamera camera;

           private FitViewport playerViewport;
        private Player player;

        public GameScreen(MenuScreen mc)
        {
            menuScreen=mc;
        }



    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        infobatch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.local("font/ornlan.fnt"));
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        manager = new AssetManager();
        manager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader());
        manager.load("world/test_1.tmx", TiledMap.class);
        manager.finishLoading();

        map = manager.get("world/test_1.tmx", TiledMap.class);

        MapProperties properties = map.getProperties();
        tileWidth         = properties.get("tilewidth", Integer.class);
        tileHeight        = properties.get("tileheight", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInTiles   = properties.get("width", Integer.class);
        mapHeightInTiles  = properties.get("height", Integer.class);
        mapWidthInPixels  = mapWidthInTiles  * tileWidth;
        mapHeightInPixels = mapHeightInTiles * tileHeight;

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(960.f, 720.f);
        playerViewport = new FitViewport(mapWidthInTiles, mapHeightInTiles, camera);

        camera.position.x = MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.x, camera.viewportWidth / 2, mapWidthInPixels - camera.viewportWidth /2);
        camera.position.y = MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.y, camera.viewportHeight / 2, mapHeightInPixels - camera.viewportHeight / 2);

        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

        player = new Player();
        inputHandler = new InputHandler();   


    }



    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.85f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.position.set(Player.x + Player.width / 2, Player.y + Player.height / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render();


        infobatch.begin();
        font.draw(infobatch, "Test World, Dev. purposes", 10,25);
        font.draw(infobatch, "FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 1180, 700);
        infobatch.end();


        batch.begin();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

           delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
           inputHandler.update();

            player.update(delta);
            player.render(batch);

            batch.end();
    }




    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { 
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {   
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {  
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {    
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { 
        batch.dispose();
        infobatch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        renderer.dispose();
        manager.dispose();
    }




    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

And this is my "MainMenu"

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL30;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

public class MenuScreen extends Game {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    BitmapFont font;
    private Stage stage;
    private GameScreen gameScreen;
    private Texture btn_start;
    private TextureRegion btn_startRegion;
    private TextureRegionDrawable btn_startDrawable;
    private ImageButton btn_startIB;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.local("font/ornlan.fnt"));
        font.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        btn_start = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/start_btn.png"));
        btn_startRegion = new TextureRegion(btn_start);
        btn_startDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(btn_startRegion);
        btn_startIB = new ImageButton(btn_startDrawable);
        btn_startIB.setPosition(10, 250);

        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        stage.addActor(btn_startIB);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        btn_startIB.addCaptureListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Starting GameScreen...");
                    setGameScreen();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error starting GameScreen E:" + e);
                }

            };
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.67f, 0.75f, 0.98f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        font.getData().setScale(0.8f,0.8f);
        font.draw(batch, "Ornlan DevBuild (pa) v0.0.0.1", 1000, 25);
        batch.end();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); // Perform ui logic
        stage.draw();

        super.render();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    void setGameScreen() {
        gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
        setScreen(gameScreen);
    }



}
```

Comment: I think the context is a bit too broad here, as there are many subjective ways to consider something to be coded 'right'. If it works, I wouldn't worry too much about it, and post concrete questions once issues arise. If you really want code reviews or best practices, perhaps the libgdx forums are a better place to seek advice?

Comment: Please tell us why you think your code is semi working? Give us some example.

Comment: I meant this in the long run, would it cause problems for example to draw GUI - (inventory etc.), Possible memory leaks? And for the code 'Semi working' - I meant it like now the "Player" - which is just a sprite, is walking around and the camera is moving to it, but when I try to implement that the camera doesn't go off the map the whole map just jitters around when I try to walk the Player

Comment: It exists many ways to create a Game so it doesn't exist a correct way. Your way is not wrong but maybe other People will do it another way. So it doesn't exist a correct answer to your question. Ask for smaller problems like: "How can I make my game fit several Screen sizes" or "How to let the camera follow my Player" and the other people will show you how they did this and then you can decide if this is the way you will go (for you the correct way) or not.

Comment: If it's working, doesn't crash time to time, doesn't lag, doesn't freeze device...it's good!

Comment: 99% of 2D games do not need threads.